# How to payment gateway in corona sdk?

Tags: payment-gateway, coronasdk

In my app i have book items its prices is 0.99$ .there is no in-app because the book is changed by week based so i avoid in-app and also each book have different prices .so i need  concept like paypal or in-app concept or some other concept you know me help

Comment: what have you done? show us codes. You mentioned app, which platform are you working on ?

Comment: i am using corona sdk its a third party tool for both devices ios and android

Comment: i know what corona is. it has limited transaction support : http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/storeTransaction/index.html . Dynamic price is not a concern with in-app purchase.

Comment: did y explain breif of storeTransaction

Comment: @ShivanRaptor: Side note (just in case):  Please don't migrate spam (re: *Can a unlocked iphone use an pre-paid sim card with rogers?*).  Also, don't vote to migrate when you don't know the target site's faq.  Phone and phone service questions are off topic for [su].  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

corona not have any paypal plugins. so u have to use pull the paypal webpage into web view and paypal web page return two type of value.
one "thank you" message when user payment is successfully.
and second is "cancel" when user cancel the payment
so you have to get this two return value in your corona app..

Answer (score 0):

I would use the webview which I am sure you can set up. It will look nice since it is auto formatted to the mobile version of Paypal's site. However, the tricky part will be detecting when the payment is complete. You can do this by checking for the Paypal payment complete URL.which you can set yourself. If these are someone else's products, ask them to set up the url.

```
local function webListener( event )

    if event.url == "YOUR THANK YOU PAGE URL HERE" then

        print("Payment Complete")

    end

end

webView:addEventListener( "urlRequest", webListener )
```